# Merging two local files in subversion

Tags: java, svn

I destroyed my subversion tree. (I attempted to ignore a few files, broke something, and now the svn says it can't find my root directory, even though it correctly notes the differences between files in said directory.) So, now I have about twenty files from my current project that I'd like to commit but can't.

I ended up checking out a new tree entirely, but now I don't know how to intelligently merge my files from the broken tree to the new tree I just checked out. I don't want to simply copy the files, as this will wipe changes others have done since I've updated. (The broken tree doesn't let me update.) Using 'svn merge' isn't meant to be used on two local copies, right? What tools can I use?

Comment: Can you just use kdiff3?

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 with Silk SVN. (I can't remember the version num, but I don't think it's important.)

Comment: The reason why I was asking is that it effects which diff/merge tool you can use. I would use the built in TortoiseSvn diff tool to merge the files but there are a lot of options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) and manually merge your changes into the repository. Then commit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can find better merging tool than [winmerge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winmerge/)

BTW - I didn't like the kdiff3 :)

Comment: WinMerge doesn't support three-way merge (and there are "no plans to implement it") .. so, yes I can ;) It does have a nice looking UI though.